# Using Webaudio in vscode extension

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions, web-audio-api

I wrote a vscode extension that creates a webview panel and I'd like to play an audio buffer when the user clicks a button on my page. I have this identical code working in a test page in a browser so I think I'm doing the webaudio part correctly.

I initialized with `vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(...)`.

When I click the button on the page, it looks like the code is working (there are no errors thrown and the expected code path happens) but I don't hear any sound.

Is there something muting the sound in the webview? Is there something I have to do to tell vscode that sound is expected?

Or is it just impossible to make a sound in a vscode extension?

EDIT:

One more detail that I forgot to mention. I am creating the audio buffer in javascript but I am loading a number of small `.mp3` files that I'm using as source. So it requires XHR to receive the `.mp3` file and `decodeAudioData` to decode it.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, Web Audio API works fine in a VS Code webview panel, but its support for audio file types is very limited. It can’t decode `.mp3` files or even `.wav` files.

However, an `.oga` file (Vorbis-encoded OGG) works.

Comment: Thanks. This is an audio buffer that I'm creating from scratch but I am assembling them from `.mp3` input. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: [Support for MP3 may be coming soon as VS Code is currently exploring the implementation of a video/audio player.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/161823)

Comment: Cool! I was hoping to get to this last week but didn't. Maybe it will just fix itself. Thanks for the info.